# Use one dataframe to match values of x in another dataframe in Pandas and return y

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Pandas dataframes, The first one (say `A` has three columns `x1`, `x2` and `y`.) The second dataframe (sat `B` has two columns `x1` and `x2`.) I want to match values of `x1` and `x2` in the two dataframes and use the `y` column of the first dataframe (`A`) to obtain values of `y` in the second dataframe (`B`).

For example, say `A` is of the following form.

```
      x1  x2         y
0      0    2  0.002255
1      0    6 -0.000427
2      1    7  0.006804
3      1    8 -0.000287
4      1    9 -0.000391
```

And `B` is like below

```
      x1  x2   
0      0    2  
1      1    7 
2      1    9
```

I am using this presently:

```
yp = B[['x1', 'x2']].map(A).rename('y')
print yp.head()
```

Here, I am expecting `yp` to be `[0.002255, 0.002255, -0.000391]`

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'
```

What am I missing here? I will very much appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you need `B[['x1', 'x2']].merge(A, how='left')` ?

Comment: When you say "predict" - are you actually trying to use some kind of predictive model? Or is this literally just matching the x-values?

Comment: miradulo: I am just looking for matching the x-values. I will edit the question to make it clearer. Thanks for the useful suggestion.

Comment: @SiddTheKid No problem, you should be careful with your use of the word _predict_, it is pretty misleading in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join:

```
yp = B[['x1', 'x2']].merge(A, how='left')
print (yp)
   x1  x2         y
0   0   2  0.002255
1   1   7  0.006804
2   1   9 -0.000391
```

Comment: Maybe it *is* the intent - I really don't know :-)

Comment: @AmiTavory - yes, maybe.

Answer (score 2):

Using something like [`sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html), you could do something like

```
from sklearn import linear_model

linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(A[['x1', 'x2']], A['y']).predict(B[['x1', 'x2']])
```

You can, of course, use any other regressor of the dozens that are part of `sklearn`, but they all follow this `fit`-`predict` pattern.

Comment: @miradulo Yeah, you're absolutely right. Many thanks - corrected.